# Authorize user programatically in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I need to authorize users programatically.

I have the authorize attribute around my controller:

```
  [Authorize]
  public class ProductsController : Controller
```

In another controller action, I'm invoking a webservice which returns an account number if successful. If not, it will return an error. Basically if the if condition is true I want to authorize user across the rest of the site.

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.AccountNumber))
 {
   //Write code to Authorize user to use the rest of the site...
   then redirect to a page on my site.
 }else
 {
  //not authorized,
 }
```

The users of the site will be admins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but since there's nothing but crickets here, I thought I'd redirect anyone coming here to [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419196/asp-net-mvc-custom-authorization?rq=1), which seems to do a decent job covering this topic.